# how to read string in Array ([2622232] => [] => apple ) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to read string in session array.

Here is the code I entered `$fruit_type` into my session:($number is 2622232 here)

```
$_SESSION['fruit'][$number]=$fruit_type;
```

When I used `print_r($_SESSION['fruit'])`, I get the following array:

```
Array ( [2622232] => [] => apple )
```

My question is how can I get the string "apple"? My editor give me error message when I tried to use `$_SESSION['fruit'][$number][]` to read string.

Any idea about my situation?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['fruit'])` and fix code which adds `apple` to array.

Comment: do a var_dump(), on your value, because it's odd about having an element without key

Comment: probably your $fruit_type is array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get that `print_r()` output is with an empty string as key `['']`, so you need to find where you do that and fix it.  However you can access it:

```
echo $_SESSION['fruit'][2622232][''];
```

Comment: Yes,yes. I double checked my code, there was a typo in my code. Right now, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['fruit'][$number][]` is wrong as you don't pass an `index`. Something like `$_SESSION['fruit'][$number][0]` should work.

You can find more information about arrays in the PHP documentation ([here the example that solves your problem](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-61))

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry that I cannot give you the "check mark", AbraCadaver's answer is more closed to my issue.